# Fraudulent transaction

Tags: transaction-fees, fraud

I have been in contact with a blockchain group and they are supposed to have a large amount of money sitting in my wallet waiting for withdrawal. I have had to send a large amount of money to try to get and each time am met with some excuse of why they cannot complete it. What can I do? Is there a way to even get my initial money back?

Comment: Probably no... Sadly this sounds like you fell for a scam. Don't send any more money.

Answer (score 3):

They don't have any money sitting in your wallet waiting for your withdrawal. They're just scamming you. Stop sending them money immediately.